# How can I check if a range of two numbers is between any range in BBDD? PHP

Tags: php, laravel, algorithm, numbers, range

My question is the following:

I have in database 2 fields called "min_amount" and "max_amount" and between them they form a range of numbers.

For example: min: 0 and max: 1000

What I am trying to do is to check if, before inserting a new range, it is between another existing range.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
        foreach ($ranges as $range){ // $range is every row in table
            $min = $range[0]; //the min value of BBDD row
            $max = $range[1]; // the max value of BBDD row
            $imin = $input["min_amount"]; // My min value I want to insert
            $imax = $input["max_amount"]; // My max value I want to insert
            if ($imin < $max || $imax > $min){
                $inrange = true;
            }
        }
```

How would you solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Say the DB has rows with collisions for this new range, what would you wish to do?

Comment: what I want to know is precisely how I can prevent one range from collapsing with another.

Comment: Ok, from where are you getting this new ranges?

Comment: You probably need `$imin < $max && $imax > $min`  for `$imin` and `$imax` between `$min` and `$max`. Otherwise if you have values like (0, 1000) and an existing range of (2000, 3000) then `$imin < $max` will be true but the whole new range is outside the existing range

Comment: @apokryfos You're right, this way I can check if it fits in the range or not, and I have added something like  ```$imin <= $max && $imax >= $min``` so that they never coincide. Thank you so much, i will test It but in principle it works great

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to check the new range against all the existing ranges. In that case you can get the highest min value and the lowest max value of all the existing ranges and compare them against your new range:

```
$highestMinValue = max(array_column($range, 0));
$lowestMaxValue = min(array_column($range, 1));

if ($highestMinValue > $lowestMaxValue ) {
    //hopefully you don't have this, but think if it happens how will you handle it
}

$imin = $input["min_amount"];
$imax = $input["max_amount"];
if ($highestMinValue <= $imin) && ($imax <= $lowestMaxValue) {
    $inrange = true;
}
```